# Access Image from Android Device

Tags: android, image

How can I access an image that has the path "DCIM/Camera/test.jpg" ? (DCIM is in the top level directory when I open the Android device in Android File Transfer. )

Comment: What do you mean by 'access an image?' Are you trying to load it into an ImageView?

Comment: Yes, I am trying to load it into an ImageView. I know how to do that once I can access the File.

Comment: Try after grant the permissions in your manifest   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_OWNER_DATA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now that we know you're trying to load it into an ImageView:

```
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.yourImageView);
Bitmap bMap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile("/sdcard/DCIM/Camera/" + yourFileName);
imageView.setImageBitmap(bMap);
```

And as Aerrow mentioned, you need to make sure you have the proper permissions in your manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: great thanks, i only needed your second line, as i mentioned before i knew how to do the imageview stuff